# Can't find Cell Based view in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm working through Cocoa Programming, in chapter 8 it says "Use the Attributes Inspector to make sure that the table view’s Content Mode is set to Cell Based" - although there doesn't appear to be any option to do that. I continued with the chapter but when I run the application at the end I can't add things to the table view. I think the cell based option may be the culprit. Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Comment: What version number does Xcode state in its About panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that You are selecting `NSScollView` and not `NSTableView` because if You put `NSTableView` in Your code from IB You have **`NSTableView` embed in a `NSScrollView`**. So if You want to select `NSTableView` You need to push slowly to times on Your TableView in Interface Builder or You can select it like this:

[image: how to select tableView]

And than go to Attributes inspector:

[image: Attributes inspector]

Comment: You're right, I was looking at NSScrollView. Unfortunately it still won't work so I must have missed something else...

Answer (score 1):

Like the book says, select the table view and look at the Attributes Inspector.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode 4.3.1, showing an NSTableView selected in a nib, with the Attributes Inspector showing its Content Mode set to Cell Based.]

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter this problem in Xcode 4.2 for Snow leopard 10.6.8. It seems that this edition doesn't have this attribute for UITableview, also doesn't support ARC for cocoa application for Mac. And I suppose that the table view application in Mac OS X 10.6 or earlier is cell-based acquiescently. Until in Mac OS X 10.7 or later ,it supports view-based mode. But I am not sure about it. Reference from http://saoqiao.com/3g/cocoa/753